# how to draw left and right rectangle sliders over x-axis of d3 graph chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I want to draw `2 rectangle sliders` over `x-axis` of the `d3 graph chart`. 
My graph chart is here https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/Lkdcw0em/4/
Now 2 `rectangle sliders` will be placed at `extreme left` of `x-axis` and `extreme right` of `x-axis`. Also while sliding the `rectangles` it will overlap that slided section, kind of making that slided section blur. Here is screenshot similar to what I am trying to draw

[image]

Comment: Finally fixed it here https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/Lkdcw0em/5/ . But having some tough time making multiple similar graph charts in a single page.For single graph chart its working fine.Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/60rrwb0n/ Fixed it. Final working copy is here.

Drew 2 `rectangles` and implemented the `drag feature`

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple working range selection tool:

http://bl.ocks.org/paradite/71869a0f30592ade5246

You could modify the behavior of the clicking on the border and change the height to fixed value to get your rectangle slider.

Comment: thanks for the reply @paradite . I have build something like this https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/erg8jypp/  little more closer to my requirement.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/Lkdcw0em/5/  @paradite here is my final modified working copy. But I am not able to make it work when trying to draw multiple graph charts in a single page.